# Invalid tag name - django tastypie

Tags: python, django, serialization, tastypie

I keep getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
>   response = wrapped_callback(request, callback_args, *callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.6.0.5/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 485, in wrapper
>   return wrapped(args, *kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.6.0.5/newrelic/hooks/component_tastypie.py", line 49, in inner_fn_wrapper
>   return inner_fn(args, *kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/src/django-tastypie-master/tastypie/api.py", line 78, in wrapper
>   return getattr(self, view)(request, args, *kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/src/django-tastypie-master/tastypie/api.py", line 155, in top_level
>   serialized = self.serializer.serialize(available_resources, desired_format, options)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/src/django-tastypie-master/tastypie/serializers.py", line 203, in serialize
>   serialized = getattr(self, "to_%s" % desired_format)(bundle, options)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/src/django-tastypie-master/tastypie/serializers.py", line 410, in to_xml
>   return tostring(self.to_etree(data, options), xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
>
> File "/app/.heroku/src/django-tastypie-master/tastypie/serializers.py", line 294, in to_etree
>   element.append(self.to_etree(value, options, name=key, depth=depth+1))
>
> File "/app/.heroku/src/django-tastypie-master/tastypie/serializers.py", line 291, in to_etree
>   element = Element(name or 'object')
>
> File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2841, in lxml.etree.Element (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:66367)
>
> File "apihelpers.pxi", line 110, in lxml.etree._makeElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:14784)
>
> File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1573, in lxml.etree._tagValidOrRaise (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:28777)
>
> ValueError: Invalid tag name u'user/photos'

The error comes from serializers.py:

```
if lxml is None:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Usage of the XML aspects requires lxml and defusedxml.")
return tostring(self.to_etree(data, options), xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you think the errors is being raised at `if lxml...`? This happens when you serialize or deserialize your XML? And only on production?

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, I am not sure it's caused there. It happens in all environments, also when testing locally.

Comment: When serialize or deserialize?

Comment: Serialize. Maybe the problem is in our version of django-tastypie.